# F# this expression was expected to have type EventHandler but here has type unit

Tags: c#, ios, multithreading, f#, xamarin

In C# Xamarin iOS I can do this:

```
InvokeOnMainThread( () => { //do stuff here});
```

where the argument for InvokeOnMainThread is NSAction

In F# I have

```
InvokeOnMainThread ( fun _ -> //do stuff here)
```

but I am getting the error "this expression was expected to have type EventHandler but here has type unit".  Why?  How can I work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F# compiler doesn't automatically convert an F# function to `NSAction`.

You can do it manually though:

```
InvokeOnMainThread (new NSAction(fun _ -> (* do stuff here *)))
```

Comment: this is still giving me the problem "this expression was expected to have type EventHandler but here has type unit"

Comment: Could you give a more complete example? It might occur due to other parts of the code.